# getting unauthorized error in javascript, how to handle basic authentication in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to get data in the table using api.im and getting an error - `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`. Api has basic authentication with userid and password (abc:abc). How to pass userid,password and authorize the api in the jquery function?

```
<head>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
        }
            table tr:nth-child(odd) {
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
            }
            table tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: #ffffff;
            }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                <td>{{ x.id}}</td>
                <td>{{ x.name }}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://example.com/node1", { userid:"abc", password:"123"})
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have jquery code.

Comment: sorry , can u share any link of jquery where basic authentication is handled

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the header attribute as a parameter in the get function:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('https://example.com/node1', {
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic user:pass' }
   }).then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
}
```

This will work only for this request. You can also set up a http interceptor for all the requests.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/node1. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5810' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/node1. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’